# export data in a list and array to excel using c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of numbers in one class. I am trying to export the data in the list and the data in array[4,4] to Excel. I would like the list as one column with the header and the array as a table with headers (column name) and row names.

I did not find a proper solution to try

```
   public void Data_to_Excel()
    {

        //start excel
        NsExcel.Application excapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        //if you want to make excel visible           
        excapp.Visible = true;

        //create a blank workbook
        var workbook = excapp.Workbooks.Add(NsExcel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

        //or open one - this is no pleasant, but yue're probably interested in the first parameter
        string workbookPath = " filepath here ";
        workbook = excapp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);


        //Not done yet. You have to work on a specific sheet - note the cast
        //You may not have any sheets at all. Then you have to add one with NsExcel.Worksheet.Add()
        var sheet = (NsExcel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1]; //indexing starts from 1

        //do something usefull: you select now an individual cell
        //var range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
        //range.Value2 = "test"; //Value2 is not a typo

        //now the list
        string cellName;
        int counter = 1;
        foreach (var item in Sim_Obj.Bottom_Rows_Count_Stack)
        {
            cellName = "A" + counter.ToString();
            var range = sheet.get_Range(cellName, cellName);
            range.Value2 = item.ToString();
            ++counter;
        }

        workbook.SaveAs("Cash_Surge_Sim_Results.xlsx");


    }
```

I have the 20 results in the rich text box in a list.
I have table layout data in an array[4,4]

I want the array data as a table form in Excel and 
the list data as one column.

Comment: So you're trying to export numbers from a C# list and an array to Excel? It's easiest just to dump that data into a CSV, and then load the CSV into Excel. Look into using CsvHelper, but for simple applications you can even just write out the values to a file separated by commas yourself.

Comment: could you please help me with the code?